# I'm trying to search an item but the program gives incorrect result

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-search

I wrote a program for linear search in python but it doesn's work correctly.

I tried double checking the program  but I couldn't find the mistake.

```
def LinearSearch(arr, n):

    for i in arr:
        if i == n:
            return i
        else:
            return -1

def main():

    arr1 = [10, 20, 80, 30, 60, 50, 110, 100, 130, 170]
    n1 = 110

    arr2 = [10, 20, 80, 30, 60, 50, 110, 100, 130, 170]
    n2 = 175

    result1 = LinearSearch(arr1, n1)
    if result1 == n1:
        print('Item %d found at index %d' % (n1, result1))
    else:
        print('Item not found')

    result2 = LinearSearch(arr2, n2)
    if result2 == n2:
        print('Item %d found at index %d' % (n2, result2))
    else:
        print('Item not found')

main()
```

I expected output 'Element x is present at index 6' for the first search but it says 'Item not found'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `LinearSearch` function always met the `return` for any case and the function is just ended when it met `return` without looping. Thus, the function only gives `-1` because the first element for each list is `10` which is not matching with `110` and `175`.

Here is my modification.

```
def LinearSearch(arr, n):

    count = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i == n: return count
        else: count += 1
    return -1    

def main():

    arr1 = [10, 20, 80, 30, 60, 50, 110, 100, 130, 170]
    n1 = 110

    arr2 = [10, 20, 80, 30, 60, 50, 110, 100, 130, 170]
    n2 = 175

    result1 = LinearSearch(arr1, n1)
    if result1 != -1: print('Item %d found at index %d' % (n1, result1))
    else: print('Item not found')

    result2 = LinearSearch(arr2, n2)
    if result2 != -1: print('Item %d found at index %d' % (n2, result2))
    else: print('Item not found')

main()
```